# Debian Stable , just updated, Nvidia drivers didn't get built/brought to current kernel via dkms. How to build/activate after update?

Tags: debian, secure-boot, dkms

Debian Stable , just updated,  Nvidia drivers didn't get built/brought  to current kernel via `dkms`. How to build/activate after update?

I have a `Debian 11 stable` install, (Secure Boot is enabled) that i recently updated.
It went from `5.10.0-18-amd64` to `5.10.0-21-amd64`, kernel wise.

However, the `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-SMI` commands don't work- and I've noticed in my `/usr/lib/modules/5.10.0-21-amd64`  directory , that it doesn't have the `/updates/dkms` folder  I see in the other kernel i have ,
`/lib/modules/5.10.0-18-amd64/updates/dkms`  which has 5 nvidia module files in it.

Prior to the update, a few months back I had uncommented/enabled
`sign_tool="/etc/dkms/sign_helper.sh"` in `/etc/dkms/framework.conf`
after being told `dkms` is how you update without having to sign nvidia modules every single time you update on a secure-boot enable system.

Currently trying to figure out what is going wrong. I did run `sudo dkms status`, and it gives
`nvidia-current, 470.161.03: added`
i've read it's supposed to say installed, not added.

Possibly releveant info: `/lib/modules` actually has a few kernel directories

```
5.10.0-10-amd64  
5.10.0-11-amd64  
5.10.0-13-amd64  
5.10.0-15-amd64 
 5.10.0-18-amd64 
 5.10.0-21-amd64
```

of all of those, only 11 and 18 have `/updates/dkms/(bunch of nvidia modules)`
Are those old folders causing an issue? I currently only have the 18 and 21 kernels on the system now currently anyway, after a apt autoremove was performed after the update.

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia drivers the first time around?

Comment: Pretty sure it was  sudo apt install nvidia-driver

I don't think i did anything special - just as far as installation goes. 
 At a certain point after install i looked into and then made mok keys and started signing kernel modules due to Secure Boot (before i looked into how to avoid having to do that) , but that was post-install of course

Comment: Nvidia drivers from the repository should work with dkms.

Comment: SOLVED

I had to clear out EVERYTHING  in 
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/470.161.03 with   rm -f 

then did the same to everything in /lib/moduless, then used locate dkmsnvidia*.ko , to ensure no more modules were around, not even in the prior kernel18's folder

then i installed the drivers again, and did a sudo update-initramfs and rebooted
-And from here, the modules were in the /libmodules/5.10.0-21-amd64/updates/dkms folder which appeared now. nvidia smi and settings STILL didnt work-   i manually signed the ko modules, that got it. Oddly old kernel files blocked proper updating.